# Where do you find "dim." within musescore?

Tags: musescore

Where is  ***dim***. found within musescore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are found in the "Lines" palette (on the left side of the screen). You can use both text versions (dim.) or hairpins.

See more [here](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/hairpin) in MuseScore's online handbook.